# Submit datas to UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

Is there a way to submit datas to a webpage (shown via UIWebView)?

Hi the problem I have: My App has stored the login datas of a user. Now I want to submit these datas to a UIWebView to log the user in. Is there a way and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make an html and within the body of that use data login dates.

```
NSString *datesDataHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>%@</BODY></HTML>", loginDatesiFrame];

    [_webView loadHTMLString:datesDataHTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Answer (score 0):

make a 
`NSString *str = [NSString striwithformat:@"str %@",appendstring];` 
and load the string using the **loadHTMLString** function.